# Failed to run the react native application locally

Tags: react-native

Using `react-native init FirstApp` i created a sample project and while i'm trying to run the app using `react-native run-android` i'm getting the following error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

````
A problem occurred configuring root project 'MyFirstApp'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not download builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.4.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.4.1/builder-3.4.1.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.4.1/builder-3.4.1.jar'.
            > Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/172.217.212.91, dl.google.com/172.217.212.190, dl.google.com/172.217.212.93, dl.google.com/172.217.212.136] failed: Connection timed out: connect
   > Could not download manifest-merger.jar (com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.4.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/26.4.1/manifest-merger-26.4.1.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/26.4.1/manifest-merger-26.4.1.jar'.
            > Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/74.125.124.190, dl.google.com/74.125.124.93, dl.google.com/74.125.124.136, dl.google.com/74.125.124.91] failed: Connection timed out: connect```

Can somebody help me out here?
````

Comment: Even to escape initial error, I changed the distribution URL in `gradle-wrapper.properties` file, here it is:

`distributionUrl=gradle-5.4.1-all.zip` but still i'm facing the above error

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by setting up the proxy configuration.
Set the following configuration in `gradle.properties` file

```
# HTTP proxy configuration
systemProp.http.proxyHost=your.proxy.host
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.proxyUser=username
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password

# HTTPS proxy configuration
systemProp.https.proxyHost=your.proxy.host
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyUser=username
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=password
```